# Implement the constraints requiring the participants to sign the transaction in the IOUContract code

Tags: corda

I was going through Corda training material and there is one activity "Impose a constraint on the required signatures in IOUContract.verify". How to implement this constraint requiring both the participant (lender and borrower) to sign the
transaction? 
If anybody is aware of then please let me know.
My code:

```
    if (!((command.getSigners().contains(state.getLender().getOwningKey())) && (command.getSigners().contains(state.getBorrower().getOwningKey()))))
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Both lender and borrower together only may sign IOU issue transaction.");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, everyone for the detailed explanation. I have implemented the below code and it's working fine now.

```
List<PublicKey> signers = tx.getCommands().get(0).getSigners();
HashSet<PublicKey> signersSet = new HashSet<>();
for (PublicKey key: signers) {signersSet.add(key);}

List<AbstractParty> participants = tx.getOutputStates().get(0).getParticipants();
HashSet<PublicKey> participantKeys = new HashSet<>();
for (AbstractParty party: participants) {participantKeys.add(party.getOwningKey());}

require.using("Both lender and borrower together only may sign IOU issue transaction.", signersSet.containsAll(participantKeys) && signersSet.size() == 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks legit. 

If you cannot pass the test, please make sure the getter of the lender and the borrower are correct in the IOUState class.

If you are uncertain, you can look into this [contract class example.](https://github.com/corda/bootcamp-cordapp/blob/v4/src/main/java/examples/ArtContract.java)

Also, you can check [here](https://github.com/corda/bootcamp-cordapp/blob/v4/Solutions.md) for an alternative syntax to implement the contract class.

Answer (score 0):

The code you paste in is from the `contract` of a cordapp. You will initiate the signature collection in the flow of the cordapp.

Let's assume the case that there are only lender and borrower in this transaction (no third party moderator), and the lender is the flow initiator. The lender will draft the state and sign it himself, and sent a half signed transaction to the borrower via a session and the borrower will check it and sign it via the responder.

At that moment you will have a fully signed transaction. 
As for code, I would suggest you to take look at this simple negotiation cordapp for reference. https://github.com/corda/samples/blob/release-V4/negotiation-cordapp/workflows-kotlin/src/main/kotlin/negotiation/flows/AcceptanceFlow.kt

```
 val partStx = serviceHub.signInitialTransaction(txBuilder)

 // Gathering the counterparty's signature.
 val counterparty = if (ourIdentity == input.proposer) input.proposee else input.proposer
 val counterpartySession = initiateFlow(counterparty)
 val fullyStx = subFlow(CollectSignaturesFlow(partStx, listOf(counterpartySession)))
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The state contract will enforce who are the required signers. In [this example](https://github.com/corda/samples/tree/release-V4/cordapp-example), the contract is expecting [all participants](https://github.com/corda/samples/blob/70d5d44b3a7327e1b050cc9d990d667b95d41e2d/cordapp-example/contracts-java/src/main/java/com/example/state/IOUState.java#L49-L50) (i.e. lender and borrower) to be [required signers](https://github.com/corda/samples/blob/70d5d44b3a7327e1b050cc9d990d667b95d41e2d/cordapp-example/contracts-java/src/main/java/com/example/contract/IOUContract.java#L46-L47) of the `Create` command.
2. When the flow is crafting a transaction to create a new IOU, it must specify [which command](https://github.com/corda/samples/blob/70d5d44b3a7327e1b050cc9d990d667b95d41e2d/cordapp-example/workflows-java/src/main/java/com/example/flow/ExampleFlow.java#L91-L93) to use (`Create` IOU in our case); and who will sign this command (so the flow will work on collecting those signatures).
3. The flow will [verify the transaction](https://github.com/corda/samples/blob/70d5d44b3a7327e1b050cc9d990d667b95d41e2d/cordapp-example/workflows-java/src/main/java/com/example/flow/ExampleFlow.java#L101) before signing it, which in return will run the contract; if the requested signatures that were specified on the `Create` command inside the flow don't match what the contract is expecting to see as required signers; then the contract will fail the transaction. Otherwise the contract will pass the transaction, and the flow will proceed to collect [the signature of the lender](https://github.com/corda/samples/blob/70d5d44b3a7327e1b050cc9d990d667b95d41e2d/cordapp-example/workflows-java/src/main/java/com/example/flow/ExampleFlow.java#L106), then collect [the signature of the borrower](https://github.com/corda/samples/blob/70d5d44b3a7327e1b050cc9d990d667b95d41e2d/cordapp-example/workflows-java/src/main/java/com/example/flow/ExampleFlow.java#L150).

So in short, the contract will say who are the required signers for a certain state command, and the flow that's creating a transaction for that state/command combination must obey the contract rules by specifying the same set of signers and collect their signatures.